# Fetching link adresses with rvest

Tags: r, screen-scraping

I want to fetch the adresses of all the links to be found at this website:

http://www.marktplaats.nl/z/bureaustoel.html?query=bureaustoel&currentPage=4

Therefore I wrote the following code:

```
create_links <- function(keyword, distance) {

 data.frame <- data.frame(character(), character(), stringsAsFactors=F)
 postcode <- c(3511, 4000, 5000)

  var_website1 <- "http://www.marktplaats.nl/z.html?query="
  var_website2 <- "&postcode="
  var_website3 <- "&distance="

for (i in 1:length(postcode)) {

    website <- paste0(var_website1, keyword, var_website2, postcode[i],   var_website3, distance)

    html <- read_html(website)
    number <- html_nodes(html, "span data-url")
    print(number)
     }
    }
```

The variable number does not return a link however. It returns:

```
{xml_nodeset (0)}
```

If I hit view of the website mentioned above I get see this (row +/- 2125):

```
....
<figure class="cell column-thumb ">
            <span data-url="http://www.marktplaats.nl/a/huis-en-inrichting/bureaus-en-bureaustoelen/a1019445395-grote-voorraad-vitra-ea217-219-eames-bureaustoelen-tip.html?c=d97e27c274e75147b4afd0f5eb58c81b&previousPage=lr" class="thumb-placeholder-centered juiceless-link " title="Grote voorraad Vitra EA217/219 Eames bureaustoelen (TIP!)" data-cas-tracking="EjuiBbJSjW9sVgjIAyeExca2zcNmdAbNqxnHL3TgJyETa5q3TEDHkbBhIP9knzWvCulPWdoWiqXvcyfnSlrtRj2yyEXBtTYpthUSEEyz3_jWR5WtL1zsTojR6ptN1zVrghXZKtNjPuwefDWPO4kPTTU8raZkSZpQ0Az18CMyPs8bHLPPXWngYk4RFiRQKTi8nKsyBIq4dRTk1FDIm-rscC8MiYUK0WcmnCnF-fJEFbvwmTiI2VUwvg-VySDb9F48wEc9WcVLaD0amDazxXTK1TkM0T5jDK1oVnlC7t0fcm0xCiqHrJZCW5aIDq-RYxLgYl32mIz4pyskjhD2WnOXciaT5tAE_e61pRAWvUXMBEn4WRpS2aSdTfa9oNaPuF8W2j00kRrrIEPF-2miQv3JQATPxT4WpLurqOoXzNAfNccZHOJ6cKpgy5s7xn7AnylRm8PIh-GCos_L8FlxOIIC6BeYTveRK4M7ua3HwJCJXiJDwZ_uxvWSsOj7VWpRoLn-NFci_L2i_PbyQQbQP3bT0iMdxqoO2hV6OA3sa5rl4PyC5X92F70hiIvuUlE_nxkx_p0kq6hJCqJ54lfitU5ObgwqeO7U1mQloh8e_wFzlqC1pWuEFtnNa6t4H_aIz-HOqlHjcsAhWTqN8_zhG7MnMEr3h50Wg1a1kHgr6Sw6ckr6VQO1j2pvjZKD9KS7Hjy_v-gZrh8ggJ9qwdORv1OlUdQasEAniKExm4pCY2zKdTXB0Rqw7u_MVxp4FMr-W7UdBklWFpHQM8-vMaGYkGXrhKbRYTHXIHACby9fSca0xo_ixHOL77hRJj_SU-eKxswvvhfEgwH6g-iQlcb8mRqMs5W6CKhrPGWXMNHODgila1MCRobPPJNPrQ">
                <div class="listing-image">
```

Any thoughts on how I can retrieve the  link?

Comment: Can you please edit your code so that you display a full MWE (for example you do not mention appropriate values for keyword and distance, also you forget to load rvest)

Comment: Aside: Your `for` loop is really more complex than necessary. You don’t need `for (i in 1 : length(x))` loops in R (pretty much at all) — you’re essentially attempting to write C code in R. You can do it much simpler: `for (code in postcodes)`. And in fact you’d probably use an `lapply` instead of a loop here, making this even simpler. — Also, your web address could be constructed much simpler using `sprintf`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this, however, you probably need to filter out advertisements:

```
library(rvest)
library(magrittr)

data.frame <- data.frame(character(), character(), stringsAsFactors=F)
postcode <- c(3511, 4000, 5000)
keyword <- "bureaustoel"
distance <- 3000

var_website1 <- "http://www.marktplaats.nl/z.html?query="
var_website2 <- "&postcode="
var_website3 <- "&distance="

for (i in 1:length(postcode)) {

  website <- paste0(var_website1, keyword, var_website2, postcode[i],   var_website3, distance)

  cont <- website %>% read_html()

  cont <- cont %>% html_nodes(xpath = "/html/body/div[2]/div/div[4]/div[2]/section[2]")

  number <- cont %>% html_children %>% length
  print(number)
  # with postcode = 3511, you get:
  # [1] 41
}
```

The tricky part is finding the `xpath`, which you can do with Firebug in Firefox or using Chrome.

You find another example on how to use rvest in this blogpost: https://datashenanigan.wordpress.com/2015/04/30/using-rvest-and-dplyr-to-look-at-aviation-incidents/

Comment: Does that give you the answer you where looking for? If so, please consider upvoting and marking it as the answer. Thank you!